# Strange Modal View Controller NSException bug

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, crash-reports, nsexception

Can anyone help me make sense of the crash log below? It came from Apple after inquiring further about a crash my app had. They rejected the app because of this crash, but I have never once been able to make it occur on my end or with 10+ beta testers. So basically, it is only occurring for them for some reason. It looks like it has to do with presenting a view, but that's weird because, like I said, this view is coming up perfectly fine.

```
    Mar 11 14:46:09 unknown StageBloc[2309] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AccountOverviewViewController popupViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2c7820'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x3291964f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x36b5cc5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x3291d1bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x3291c649 ___forwarding___ + 508
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x32893180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5   AppName                           0x0004b56d -[TTBaseViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] + 36
    6   UIKit                               0x35b0dead -[UIViewController _isSupportedInterfaceOrientation:] + 48
    7   UIKit                               0x35b76e51 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:] + 68
    8   UIKit                               0x35b75f07 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 794
    9   UIKit                               0x35b756f7 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 2378
    10  UIKit                               0x35b74cd7 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 58
    11  StageBloc                           0x00009bb1 -[StageBlocViewController loginSuccessful] + 196
    12  StageBloc                           0x00004c21 -[StageBlocAppDelegate successfulAttempt:] + 288
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x32886f03 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 22
    14  AppName                           0x0002aa75 -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] + 60
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x32886f03 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 22
    16  Foundation                          0x325707a9 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 268
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x328f0a79 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x328f275f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 382
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x328f34eb __CFRunLoopRun + 230
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x32883ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x32883dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x30b2b41f GSEventRunModal + 114
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x30b2b4cb GSEventRun + 62
    24  UIKit                               0x35af9d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
    25  UIKit                               0x35af7807 UIApplicationMain + 670
    26  AppName                           0x00002ae1 main + 48
    27  AppName                           0x00002aac start + 40
)
```

Comment: Having similar issue (objects that recognize selectors don't , I have suspicions it's something to do with linking...)

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with forgetting to add some required built variables to my project that the Three20 libraries use. I didn't notice it because you can't run App Store release builds locally.